# How to remove observer using ReactiveCocoa?

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-cocoa

How to stop receiving new name after some event?

```
[RACObserve(self, username) subscribeNext:^(NSString *newName) {
    if ([newName isEqualToString:@"SomeString"])
    {
       //Do not observe any more
    }
}];
```

P.S. Sorry for obvious question, but I can't find answer

Answer (score 11):

You can use method 'dispose' of RACDisposable object which be returned from 'subscribeNext'.

```
__block RACDisposable *handler = [RACObserve(self, username) subscribeNext:^(NSString *newName) {
    if ([newName isEqualToString:@"SomeString"]) {
        //Do not observe any more
        [handler dispose]
    }
}];
```

Comment: Thanks! That's what I wanted to see.

Comment: If `self.username` is equal to  'SomeString' before this line of code, the handler will not dispose, am I right?

Answer (score 9):

It's important to think about things a little differently in ReactiveCocoa: you don't want to "remove" an observer, you want to create a signal that completes when something happens.

You can use `takeUntilBlock:` to derive a signal that will stop sending values after a certain time:

```
[[RACObserve(self, username) takeUntilBlock:^(NSString *name) {
    return [name isEqualToString:@"something"];
}] subscribeNext:^(NSString *name) {
    NSLog(@"%@", name);
}];
```

But that will not send a next for the string `@"something"`, only the names before it. If that's desired, you could append it:

```
NSString *sentinel = @"something";
[[[RACObserve(self, username) takeUntilBlock:^(NSString *name) {
    return [name isEqualToString:sentinel];
}] concat:[RACSignal return:sentinel]] subscribeNext:^(NSString *name) {
    NSLog(@"%@", name);
}];
```

It's not very elegant, but you could make a `takeUntilBlockInclusive` helper that would get you this behavior, and hide the grossness in there.